# why, when, and how should a writestream be closed?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my code

```
let file = writeFile(filename, destination)
```

I call this  after I request a link and the pipe it.

```
reponse.pipe(file)
```

my write function

```
 function writeFile(filename, destination) {
   // console.log('ad',dir);
   let num = 1;

   let nm_wo_ext = filename.substr(0, filename.lastIndexOf("."));
   let ext = filename.split(".").pop();
   let jpath = path.join(destination, filename);

   while (fs.existsSync(jpath)) {
     // let f = nm_wo_ext  + '('(num++) +ext
     filename = `${nm_wo_ext} (${num++}).${ext}`;

     jpath = path.join(destination, filename);
     // console.log({jpath});
   }
   // fs.writeFileSync(jpath,data )

   return fs.createWriteStream(jpath);
 }
```

how does closing the createwritestream work here?

Comment: So you're piping a read stream in to a write stream?

Comment: No,I'm downloading an image from a link and piping it.

Comment: Ok, so you can do something like file.on('end', ()=>{console.log('file saved'); file.end();}); this will close the stream when the file is fully processed.